# open_note() missing 1 required positional argument: 'docid'

Tags: python, django, django-views

I appreciate that this question has been asked multiple times before, and I have looked at basically all of the answers and the official documentation for django, but I still can not figure out why I am getting the Exception Value of: open_note() missing 1 required positional argument: 'docid'.

I am trying to get the page to display the selected document from the database, when it loads it should show the title and the content, along with an edit and delete button (neither of which function yet, but they're not important right now). The request url is `http://localhost:8000/notes/open-notes/?docid=1`, and it leads to the error mentioned above.

If I change my urls.py path to `path('open-notes/<int:id>/', views.open_note, name='open-notes'),` then the error I get instead is `Reverse for 'open-notes' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['notes/open\\-notes/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$']` which I assume is because the id isn't actually an int and needs converting in the views.py, or I need to use a different converter in the urls.py.

Or equally entirely possible, I've misunderstood the other answers in which case I apologise for asking the same question that already has an answer I should be able to implement. I am relatively new to django and just trying to expand my knowledge base, any and all help is greatly appreciated.

My notes.html:

```
{% block content %}
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-7 col-md-6 my-auto">
            <h1 class="display-4 logo-font text-black">
                Campaign Notes
            </h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2">
            <ul class="logo-font font-weight-bold nav-link text-warning mr-5">
                {% for doc in documents %}
                    {% if doc.id %}    
                        <li>
                            <a href="{% url 'open-notes' %}?docid={{ doc.id }}" class="logo-font font-weight-bold nav-link text-warning mr-5">
                                {{ doc.title }}
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    {% else %}
                        <p class="logo-font font-weight-bold nav-link text-warning mr-5">No documents available</p>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
            <a href="{% url 'add-notes' %}?docid={{ doc.id }}" class="logo-font font-weight-bold nav-link text-warning mr-5">
                <i class="fas fa-file-alt"></i> New document
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

My views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404

from .models import Document
from .forms import DocumentForm


def view_notes(request):
    """
    A view to show all campaign notes for the user,
    including sorting and search queries
    """
    docid = request.POST.get('docid')
    documents = Document.objects.all()

    context = {
        'docid': docid,
        'documents': documents,
    }

    return render(request, 'notes.html', context)

# Create


def add_note(request):
    """ A view to create a new document """
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST.get)

        if form.is_valid:
            title = form.cleaned_data['title']
            content = form.cleaned_data['content']
            document = Document(title=title, content=content)
            document.save()
    else:
        form = Document()

    return render(request, 'add-notes.html', {'form': form})

# Read


def open_note(request, docid):
    """ A view to show the currently open document """
    docid = get_object_or_404(Document, pk=docid)
    documents = Document.objects.all(pk=docid)

    context = {
        'docid': docid,
        'documents': documents,
    }

    return render(request, 'open-notes.html', context)
```

My urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.view_notes, name='notes'),
    path('add-notes/', views.add_note, name='add-notes'),
    path('open-notes/', views.open_note, name='open-notes'),
    path('edit-note/', views.update_note, name='edit-note'),
    path('delete-note/', views.delete_note, name='delete-note'),
]
```

My open-notes.html:

```
{% block content %}
{% for doc in documents %}
    {% if doc.id == docid %}
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-7 col-md-6 my-auto">
                    <h1 class="display-4 logo-font text-black">
                        {{ doc.title }}
                    </h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <form method="POST" action="{% url 'notes' %}">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <input type="hidden" name="docid" value="{{ docid }}">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="content" class="text-warning">Content</label>
                        <textarea readonly class="form-control text-black overflow-auto" id="content" placeholder="{{ doc.content }}" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <a href="{% url 'edit-note' %}?docid={{ doc.id }}" type="submit" class="btn btn-warning text-black">Edit</a>
                        <a href="{% url 'delete-note' %}?docid={{ doc.id }}" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger text-black">Delete</a>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
path('open-notes/<int:docid>', views.open_note, name='open-notes'),

<a href="{% url 'open-notes' doc.id %}" class="logo-font font-weight-bold nav-link text-warning mr-5">
    {{ doc.title }}
</a>
```

Read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/#example

Comment: oh of course because it's looking for docid, not id, that makes sense.
Just tried it and got the error
`Reverse for 'open-notes' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['notes/open\\-notes/(?P<docid>[0-9]+)/$']`

Comment: I edited my original comment at the same time you sent yours, no it doesn't work for me unfortunately, it gives the same error as using `path('open-notes/<int:id>', views.open_note, name='open-notes'),` does

Comment: @daniel-mctighe please check the update answer

Comment: I'd love to see if it's working now but my IDE is struggling to find ports, I'll get back to you when it connects

Comment: ok that fixed it, thanks @c.grey! Now I just need to work out why it's not displaying any information on the webpage